# Which airlines allow you to gain hours with them by paying them

Tags: airliner, flight-training, general-aviation, student-pilot

As a fresh grduated pilot is there any airline that you can pay them to fly with them without a salary just to build hours?

Comment: Voting to close because it's too broad. There's a [whole list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_to_fly#Airlines_and_brokers_involved) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

There are pay to fly services, however regulations require a minimum number of hours before you can do any kind of part 121 or part 135 work. So while you can get some extra hours in Jets by paying them that way or turbo props or whatever else you’re looking for, it’s not recommended. Probably the best starting gate once you have a commercial pilot certificate is just doing flight instruction work until you gain the required 1500 hours.  After that you should have offers for most of the regional carriers to work for them as a first officer.

Answer (score -1):

None. It doesn't work that way. Airlines have employees, not volunteers or indentured servants flying their aircraft, and the law requires that employees be paid. Not always paid very much, but "flying for free" doesn't exist at any airline I've ever heard of. And I wouldn't want to ride on any that had such a program.

Comment: Incorrect. This is called [pay to fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_to_fly), is prevalent in Europe and Asia, especially with wet lease operators.

Comment: Pay to get hired was big with the US regionals in the 90s when there were more pilots than jobs.  It's only stopped with the growing shortage of crews over the last 15 years.  If you peruse old pilot bulletin board posts like on PPrune from the late 90s there is a lot of bitter discussion over the practice.

Comment: @user71659  That is frightening.  I wonder what the safety record is at such operations.  No, actually, I suspect it's an easy guess....